# SQLite3 accepts iso-8859-9 over console but not with php query

Tags: php, sqlite, character-encoding

I am working on a website with lots of Turkish words in it. And them need to be stored into the sql database. I use SQLite for some reason.
When I directly open up the sqlite3 database @ console I can insert any characters into the table without setting the charset. It accepts shows and even returns to my browser with correct characters. But when I try to insert anything in, it inserts something like this :

```
2|Kedi|kedi@kopek.  |Selfie çubuğ // This is the one I inserted via console
3|senior|senior@kaba|�ok �eker bir // This one appended by php execution.
```

Is there anything I can do to change the character charset of SQLite3?(Like in MYSQL @MySQLAdmin settings.)

Or Any way do change convert between UTF-8 and ISO-8859-9 ?

Comment: Why not just use UTF8 throughout?

Comment: UTF-8 I/O does not work correctly with `sqlite3.exe` in the Windows console.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, how are you inserting? doing a copy paste?

and what is the encoding(characterset) you have given for your form?
try this

```
<form action="turktry.php" accept-charset="ISO-8859-9">
  First name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

sqlite should not be bothered unless you are making a string search in the db, and mostly then you would need the ICU.

relation should be between what you write and how you read it back?